# Fluent NHibernate LazyLoad Issues

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I couldn't find an answer to this issue so I assume it is something I am doing wrong.

I have a PersistenceModel set up where I have set a convention as follows: -

```
persistenceModel.Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Always());
```

However, for one of the HasManyToMany relationships in one of my entities I want eager loading to take place which I am setting up as follows: -

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Affiliates).Not.LazyLoad();
```

Intuitively, I expect eager loading to take place as I am overriding the lazy load default that I have specified as a convention but it still lazy loads.  If I set the DefaultLazy convention to never and then set LazyLoad on an individual relationship it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

When you set Not.LazyLoad(), you tell NHibernate to load Affiliates when the parent loads. NHibernate will do this by performing another select on the Affliates many-to-many table regardless of whether you access the Affiliates collection or not. NHibernate is using another select because that is the default fetching mode. You want to override fetching mode as well, either in the query or in the mapping. To do it in the mapping, add the following:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Affiliates)
    .Not.LazyLoad()
    .Fetch.Join();
```

You might also want to include a ".Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()" if you want NHibernate to persist new Affiliaites added to the collection and delete orphaned ones. If you do not do this, you will have to explicitly call session.Save(newAffiliate). Otherwise you'll receive a TransientObjectException when your Affiliates collection contains a new Affiliate.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the parts of the code that I didn't think were relevant here.  I do have .FetchType.Join() also and turning off lazy loading still doesn't work.  The only way to turn off lazy loading I have found that works for me is by setting the convention.

Comment: I added the DefaultLazy.Always() convention and the HasManyToMany() relationship is correctly eager loading when Fetch.Join() is applied. You can grab my sample from GitHub here: https://github.com/JamesKovacs/JamesKovacs.StackOverflow/tree/master/FluentNhHacking/

Comment: Alright, well I pretty much mimicked your code in my situation and it still didn't work, so I will have to have a closer look.  I am using .ShowSql() to determine whether the queries have been run lazily or eagerly which I presume to be accurate?

Comment: Your sample project appears to be using XML mapping

Answer (score 0):

It may be one stupid thing to ask, but have you execute the query inside your session? Say,

```
Using(var session = OpenSession())
{
    session.Query<Entity>().ToList();
}
```

I had this problem before, and finally realized the objects that I was accessing hadn't been queried before disposing the session.